How to show that the set $ M = \{ (x,y) \mid x + 4y^2 \leq 4 \} $ is convex?
I need to show that the following set is convex using the definition:
$ M = \{ (x,y) \mid x + 4y^2 \leq 4 \} $.
I have considered 2 points: $ (x_1, y_1) \in M $, $ (x_2, y_2) \in M $. Then, we have that $ x_1 + y_1^2 \leq 4$, $ x_2 + y_2^2 \leq 4$.
I know that I need to show the following: $ (1- \alpha) x_1 + \alpha x_2 + 4 ((1- \alpha) y_1 + \alpha y_2)^2 \leq 4$.
Or, if we expand the brackets: $ (1- \alpha) x_1 + \alpha x_2 + 4 (1- \alpha)^2 y_1^2 + 4\alpha^2 y_2^2 + 8\alpha(1-\alpha)y_1y_2 \leq 4$. However, I'm not sure how I can show that this inequality holds.

Have you realized that this set is the interior of a parabola ?

The intersection of two convex sets is convex. Can you see how that's useful here?

You want to find a way to incorporate the information you have - namely that $x_1 + 4y_1^2 \leq 4$ and $x_2 + 4y_2^2 \leq 4$. As it stands, the coefficients aren't quite right, so try introducing terms that fix that. So you might get something like:
$$\begin{eqnarray} (1 - \alpha)x_1 + \alpha x_2 + 4\left[(1 - \alpha) y_1 + \alpha y_2 \right]^2 & = & (1 - \alpha) x_1 + 4 (1 - \alpha)^2 y_1^2 + \alpha x_2 + 4 \alpha^2 + 8 \alpha (1 - \alpha) y_1 y_2 \\
& = & (1 - \alpha) x_1 \color{red}{+ 4 (1 - \alpha) y_1^2 - 4 (1 - \alpha) y_1^2} + 4 (1 - \alpha)^2 y_1^2 \\ && + \alpha x_2 \color{red}{+ 4 \alpha y_2^2 - 4 \alpha y_2^2 }+ 4 \alpha^2 y_2^2 \\ && + 8 \alpha (1 - \alpha) y_1 y_2 \\
& = & (1 - \alpha)(x_1 + 4 y_1^2) + \alpha(x_2 + 4 y_2^2) \\
&& + 4(1 - \alpha)^2 y_1^2 - 4(1 - \alpha) y_1^2 + 4 \alpha^2 y_2^2 - 4 \alpha y_2^2 \\
&& + 8 \alpha(1 - \alpha) y_1 y_2
\end{eqnarray}$$
From here, you should be able to apply the given information and also do a little bit of factorisation / simplification on the remaining terms to give you something that you can then state is $\leq 4$ as long as $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$.

First note that, since the relation describing $M$ is continuous, it is sufficient to consider the case $\alpha=\frac12$. Then we continue from your attempt by using $x_i\leq 4-4y_i^2$ for $i=1,2$ to get \begin{align}
&\frac12x_1+\frac12 x_2+4\left(\frac12y_1+\frac12 y_2\right)^2\\
\leq\ &\frac12(4-4y_1^2)+\frac12(4-4y_2^2)+y_1^2+\frac12y_1y_2+y_2^2\\
=\ &4-y_1^2+\frac12y_1y_2-y_2^2\overset!\leq4,
\end{align} which is equivalent to $0\leq y_1^2-\frac12y_1y_2+y_2^2=(y_1-\frac14y_2)^2+\frac{15}{16}y_2^2$, which is obviously true since squares are nonnegative.

Here is a different, more conceptual proof: $(y,x)\in M$ is equivalent to $y\leq 4-4x^2$, so $M$ is the hypograph of $y=f(x):=4-4x^2$. The hypograph of a function is convex if and only if the function is concave. But $f$ is twice differentible, so it is enough to observe $f''(x)=-8<0$ to prove the latter.
